# Is there any way to add monitoring/alert on nexus maven2 proxy repository?

Tags: maven, nexus

I have one maven repositories “maven-central” and it’s a proxy of https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

When I take reference of a new package it is getting cached on maven-central.

Is there any way to get a notification (like email alert) when new package cached on the maven-central proxy repository?

Nexus Version: OSS 3.0.1-01 (Open to take updates or purchased version)

Comment: I'm just curious: Why do you care about the exact caching behaviour?

Comment: In case of any new package/jar cached from maven central as it will affect OSS report and I want to start other security scans. Current situation is if I define any dependency in build.gradle file, it downloads package from mavan central as I have settled proxy on nexus. In such case I want notification to be updated that development team had added new open source.

Comment: This is interesting. I guess the more standard way is to check (release) builds for problematic artifacts, but I fully understand that you want to have control beforehand.